# Calculate net trade position in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

First time posting; couldn't find anything on here that solved my question.

I have a deal table with about 630,000 entries, sample input here:

```
dealid deal_counterparty_id deal_instrument_id deal_type deal_amount
 20001                  703               1010 B             3588.81
 20002                  701               1001 S             3412.81
 20003                  701               1004 B             8527.11
 20004                  701               1011 S             2441.77
 20005                  703               1010 B             3633.33
 20006                  702               1011 S             2415.16
 20007                  704               1003 S             1426.14
 20008                  701               1012 B             1858.82
 20009                  703               1009 B             3571.77
```

I want to find the realized position for each dealer on each position. i.e. The dealer has thousands of transactions for 1 instrument for 1 counterparty, so what is the net position on that instrument for that counterparty?

I want 3 columns of: deal_counterparty_id, deal_instrument.id, net position. Since I have 20 instruments (1001-1020) with only 4 counterparties (701, 702, 703, 704), the sample output would look like this:

```
deal_counterparty_id deal_instrument_id net_position
                 701               1001  5833.34
                 701               1002 -3994.21
                 701               1003 30300.00
...
                 702               1001
```

My code (getting 0 results):

```
 select buy.deal_counterparty_id, buy.deal_instrument_id, sum(buy.deal_amount) - sum(sell.deal_amount) as net_position

 from (select deal_id, deal_counterparty_id, deal_instrument_id, deal_type, deal_amount
      from deal where deal_type = 'B') as buy

      join (select deal_id, deal_counterparty_id, deal_instrument_id, deal_type, deal_amount
      from deal where deal_type = 'S') as sell

      on buy.deal_instrument_id = sell.deal_instrument_id

 group by buy.deal_counterparty_id, buy.deal_instrument_id;
```

Thanks!

Comment: sample input+output? not like every dev is a finance guy

Comment: Sample input is the table image above, sample output would be:
deal_counterparty_id || deal_instrument_id || net position
701 || 1001 || -3495.40
701 || 1002 || 7825.01
...
701 || 1020 || 1938.23
702 || 1001 || 4726.44

Comment: Instead of the `JOIN`s, I would start with `IF( deal_type = 'B', deal_amount, - deal_amount) net_amount`.

Comment: Can you explain your problem a bit more please? at least I have no idea how the output is calculated. Would be nice if you can walk a none finance guy over so that we can help you with your problem better

Comment: sorry, not good at using comments - edited my question to include sample inputs and outputs

Comment: For example, for counterparty_id 701, instrument 1001, there might be 4000 buys and sells. For each sell, I want to add the deal_amount, and for each buy, I want to subtract the deal_amount. This is from the perspective of the bank. I want the total profit or loss for that instrument for that counter party.

Comment: This is hard to understand - from your sample data, there are no matching records. Can you post a SQLFiddle?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're asking, this should work:

```
SELECT deal_counterparty_id, deal_instrument_id, 
    SUM( IF( deal_type = 'B', - deal_amount, deal_amount) ) net_position FROM deal
    GROUP BY deal_counterparty_id, deal_instrument_id
```

That is (edited as of your last comment), I'm thinking you're treating a `deal_type` of 'B' as a negative value and a `deal_type` of 'S' as a positive then just adding everything together.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! That was much easier than I expected.

Answer (score 0):

E.g.:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(dealid INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,deal_counterparty_id INT NOT NULL
,deal_instrument_id INT NOT NULL
,deal_type CHAR(1) NOT NULL
,deal_amount DECIMAL(7,2) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(20001                  ,703               ,1010 ,'B',             3588.81),
(20002                  ,701               ,1001 ,'S',             3412.81),
(20003                  ,701               ,1004 ,'B',             8527.11),
(20004                  ,701               ,1011 ,'S',             2441.77),
(20005                  ,703               ,1010 ,'B',             3633.33),
(20006                  ,702               ,1011 ,'S',             2415.16),
(20007                  ,704               ,1003 ,'S',             1426.14),
(20008                  ,701               ,1012 ,'B',             1858.82),
(20009                  ,703               ,1009 ,'B',             3571.77);

SELECT deal_counterparty_id
     , deal_instrument_id
     , SUM(CASE WHEN deal_type = 'S' THEN -1*deal_amount ELSE deal_amount END) net_position 
  FROM my_table 
 GROUP 
    BY deal_counterparty_id
     , deal_instrument_id;
+----------------------+--------------------+--------------+
| deal_counterparty_id | deal_instrument_id | net_position |
+----------------------+--------------------+--------------+
|                  701 |               1001 |     -3412.81 |
|                  701 |               1004 |      8527.11 |
|                  701 |               1011 |     -2441.77 |
|                  701 |               1012 |      1858.82 |
|                  702 |               1011 |     -2415.16 |
|                  703 |               1009 |      3571.77 |
|                  703 |               1010 |      7222.14 |
|                  704 |               1003 |     -1426.14 |
+----------------------+--------------------+--------------+
```